# Re-enable the selected files are identical" message in winmerge

Tags: default-settings, winmerge

When two identical files are compared in winmerge the message "the selected files are identical" has a check box "don't display this message again".

Is there away to reset this setting back once it is enabled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore the default settings, uninstall and re-install WinMerge.

There is no such option in the program's settings under the menu
*Edit > Options...*

You can write about this lack in
[WinMerge Support](https://winmerge.org/support/?lang=en).

Comment: I have WinMerge 2.16 here and option has not been added. Did you check in the the Compare window for this option

Comment: I did that and after the windows restart, the setting is enabled back

Comment: @john I have checked it in 2.16.4.0 and it doesn't exist

Answer (score 5):

Use Registry Editor.
Search for Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Thingamahoochie\WinMerge\MessageBoxes.
There should be an entry 18101, change the value 1 to ffffffff.

Comment: Thanks! On my version 2.16.12.0, the entry was 42101 instead of 18101

Comment: Version 2.16.32.0 : No such registry entry.